# Why doesn't PHP's Autoload feature work in CLI mode?

Tags: php, autoload, internals

This is more for my own personal edification than anything else but, this is something that has always bothered me: Why specifically can't PHP perform "autoloading" while in CLI mode?

I've been reading this disclaimer for years, but I've never read anything that touches on why:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php:
>
> > *Note: Autoloading is not available if using PHP in CLI interactive mode.*

Does anyone know what is preventing PHP, as a language, from autoloading while working in CLI mode?

Comment: You mean it doesn't work in interactive mode (when you are typing commands at the comand line?) I remember I could run php programs that did auto loading from the command line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Autoloading on the command line works. Do note the mention of "interactive".

PHP comes with two interactive modes, but unfortunately both of them are invoked by using `php -a` on your command shell.

If PHP is compiled with readline support, you get the "interactive shell". In this mode, every command is evaluated nearly instantly, and you also get instant feedback about any parsing errors.

In this mode, autoloading works.

The other mode is called "interactive mode". This mode is void of any fancy stuff, it only emits a short message, and then you basically write a PHP script - and nothing gets done unless you close the STDIN. Only then the written code gets parsed and executed. And this is the only case where the `__autoload()` function is not called for unknown classes.

Example for an interactive shell session (using PHP 5.3.2 on Linux):

```
vagrant@lucid32:/etc/apache2$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > function __autoload($classname) {
php { echo "Autoload $classname";
php { eval("class $classname{}");
php { return true;
php { }
php > new Bar();
Autoload ▒▒Bar
php > new FooBar();
Autoload ▒▒FooBar
php > var_dump($a = get_declared_classes());
array(123) {
[0]=>
string(8) "stdClass"
[1]=>
string(9) "Exception"
[2]=>
string(14) "ErrorException"
   ... lots of internal classes here ...
[121]=>
string(3) "Bar"
[122]=>
string(6) "FooBar"
}
php >
```

Example for an interactive mode (using PHP 5.3.18 on Windows)

```
PS C:\Users\sven> php -a
Interactive mode enabled

<?php
function __autoload($class) { echo "Auto: $class"; eval("class $class {}"); }
echo "Hello World";
$x = new Foo;
var_dump($x);
var_dump($a = get_declared_classes());
^Z
Hello World
Fatal error: Class 'Foo' not found in - on line 4

Call Stack:
  100.6337    1114608   1. {main}() -:0
```

Comment: PHP's interactive shell and interactive CLI are two different things! The OP asked about autoloading not being available in the interactive CLI, nothing about the interactive shell

Comment: Then why is this comment found on the [Interactive shell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) page: "Autoloading is not available if using PHP in CLI interactive mode." And what if I run `include("/some/file")` in "interactive CLI mode"?

Comment: running `include` isn't autoloading. the autoloader is called when you write `$foo = new Bar();` when you haven't included the `bar.php` file. The comment is found in the `autoload` docs, too (link in original question), and clearly states _interactive CLI_. Perhaps notify the ppl at PHP, because their documentation on this topic is, indeed somewhat confusing or vague. On the include front, my guess would be that PHP uses the `pwd` as base-path

Comment: How do I activate "interactive shell"? And how do I activate "interactive CLI"? Assuming from running `php --help` the interactive shell is invoked with `php -a` and according to the docs it does not support autoloading. What about "interactive CLI"?

Comment: @Sven... as I said: running a CLI script is like running a file from the `STDIN`, if your script offers some interactions, you'll have to `fopen('php://stdin','r');` to read the input buffer. how can you autoload a second file if that same stream is now used to interact with the user? That's basically why, when using a PHP CLI script that is interactive _has_ to disable autoloading... I just didn't feel like going into these details, as I thought them as being self-evident

Comment: Running a CLI script is simply this: `php -f script.php`. The script might decide that it wants to read from STDIN, but this has nothing to do with opening another script file because instantiating a currently unknown class triggers the autoloading function. Opening and including files still is possible.

Comment: For God's sake: nobody said including a file is impossible: PHP is _compiled_ these days, any `include` or `require` has been performed before the script runs. If you run a script from the command line, that very script is read from the STDIN: __read the link in my answer__, it says so quite clearly. If that script itself then `fopen`'s the `sdtin` -which it has to do, or else it's not an _interactive_ command-line script- the `STDIN` is used to read the input buffer, and autoloading is impossible (because autoloading is the same as ad-hoc `include` calls != explicit `includes`).

Comment: You are wrong about require/include being done before the script is being executed. They simply cannot be evaluated without executing the script. That's why you can only include in places where code is executed at script runtime, not for example in the class member declaration. Don't confuse this with opcode caches. Single script files might be stored in opcode form, but the opcode is included on demand, not right from the start.

Answer (score 3):

The way to think about PHP's interactive CLI is basically: PHP starting an empty script, and reading a file from `PHP://stdin`, which it then parses and executes. The file location, and therefore include path, and other environment variables are ignored. The current `__FILE__`, if you will does not exist.
Well, that's just a way of looking at it, it doesn't tell the whole story (far from it), but in practice, that's the way you can think of it. There needn't be a file to start in interactive CLI, at all:

```
$ php '<?php echo "this is read from STDIN"; ?>'
```

[As can be deduced from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php):

> args...                    Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
>                                 starts with - or script is read from stdin

Comment: You fail to mention that PHP hides both interactive shell and interactive mode behind the `php -a` command, which is the root of all the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, they aren't talking about CLI they are talking about PHP interactive mode, aka `php -a`.

And why? Because it is only for testing purposes and short snipplets and if ANYTHING is autoloaded the behavior might be crazy.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php

Comment: Not necessarily crazy, why would I need to include a class file myself just because I'm running in interactive mode? Does http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php not work in interactive mode?

Comment: Did you read the question? :-) By crazy I mean unexpected "standard" php behaviour. You can run interactively in every directory and get the same results