# Confusion about include_once in php

Tags: php, include

I have this:

```
class/
    |-- A.Class.php
    |-- FactoryA.php
    |-- Database.php
    |-- Log.php
index.php
```

whereby  FactoryA.php is a `Factory` class that creates obj A and can  create/read/update/delete A from database. `Log.php` is a class that send logs to a text file `log.txt`.

`FactoryA` will require `A.Class` (to create the instance) and `Database`. All 3 classes requires `Log.php` (for debugging purpose). All `index.php` does is to create a `FactoryA` instance.

I don't know where I should place include statements. Do I `include` all files  **from** `index.php`? Or do I do it in class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use an autoloader ([see Autoloading CLasses](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)), you will have to manually include all necessary files in all dependent files. It is typically recommended that all files manage all of their own dependencies.

If I understand your dependencies, this would look like:

- **Index.php** will need to `require_once` *FactoryA.php*
- **FactoryA.php** will `require_once` *A.Class.php & Log.php*
- **A.Class.php** will `require_once` Database.php & Log.php
- **Database.php**  will `require_once` Log.php

An alternative method would be to use `__autoload` and let it fetch the needed files, as needed, for you. Thus, in your

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include './class/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
$a = new A();
```

However, **spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.** See [the PHP Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

We suggest you check out the [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) and you can probably just [use the SplClassLoader.php](https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634) gist.

You will need to rename your classes to follow namespace and path standards, but then you can just do something like:

```
//This is the only file you need to require
require_once('/path/to/SplClassLoader.php');
$classLoader = new SplClassLoader('Class', './class');
$classLoader->register();
$a = new A();
```

I have written a small CLI reference project to demonstrate, checkout [bubba-h57/AutoLoading](https://github.com/bubba-h57/AutoLoading) and run it from the command line. You should see results like:

```
[cinamon-vm] AutoLoading> php index.php 
From the factory!
From the AClass!
From the Database!
Pure win!
```

See [Why doesn't PHP's Autoload feature work in CLI mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696961/why-doesnt-phps-autoload-feature-work-in-cli-mode) for a discussion on using the autoloader from command line (cli) scripts.

Comment: so, when using SplClassLoader I don't have to worry about whether php is running in CLI or not??

Comment: I've written 1-3 PHP CLI scripts per workday using it for the past three years, I haven't worried about it. It is simple enough to test, I encourage you to try it out and explore the freedom.

Comment: I put a sample CLI script using it on github for you, just git clone and play with it. Hope you find it fun and enjoyable!

Answer (score 3):

You could use autoloading.

That means that php it self will load the class if you need it. You can define it so:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include 'class/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

If you now try to create a new object, for example A, and A isn't loaded yet, autoload will be called and the first parameter will be the class looking for.

```
$a = new A();
```

http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: but I was told that autoloading is not available if PHP is running in CLI

Comment: Yes that's right. You can't use autoload if you are running php in CLI.

Comment: @Bubba Actually it's only not available if your are using PHP in CLI interactive mode.

Comment: I'm assuming you are NOT using the CLI in interactive mode, but rather running it as a cron, scheduled task, or command line ... in which case it works just fine.

Comment: spl_autoload_register() provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using __autoload() is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Modularity is usually good, but only when everything is coherent. I'm not sure why would you want to have a separate log file?

I think your files are not really organized ATM, have you considered using a framework like Laravel/CodeIgniter?

Otherwise, when including, I would just say include the relevant files into each other, like make FactoryA include the class file and then just include your FactoryA to your index file and so.