# Why use statements can't import the namespaced PHPMailer class into the global scope in php-shell?

Tags: php, namespaces

Save the follow as send.php,it can be executed with `php -f send.php` or `127.0.0.1/send.php`, no error info as output.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require_once('/home/debian9/vendor/autoload.php'); 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
?>
```

The use statements import the namespaced PHPMailer class into the global scope, so do not need to use a FQCN( Fully-Qualified Class Name) such as 
`$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();` here,just `$mail = new PHPMailer();` is enough.

Open a php shell with php -a.

```
php > use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
php > use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
php > require '/home/debian9/vendor/autoload.php';
php > $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
PHP Warning: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in php shell code:1
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in php shell code on line 1
```

Why `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);` can't import the namespaced PHPMailer class into the global scope in php shell?
You must write `$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();` in php shell.

Comment: Have you tried to `require` the autoloader first, and then `use` the PHPMailer namespace after?

Comment: It is no use to exchange order of them,tried.

Comment: You should probably read http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696961/why-doesnt-phps-autoload-feature-work-in-cli-mode